# Is there an easy way to draw logic trees in LaTex?

Tags: diagrams, logic, logicproof

I take introductory logic and we need to draw logic trees. Our teacher doesn't accept any kind of numbering placement other than his. So I searched how-tos but I didn't see an exact version of it and since I suck at coding I thought it'd be best to ask. How do I draw this in LaTex?[image]

Comment: What you try so far? Use of the `forest`  and `amsmath` is seems to be (good) way to go.

Answer (score 2):

This will get you started with `forest`. You can use an `array` for each node.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\renewcommand{\iff}{\leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\T}{\mathrm{T\,}}
\newcommand{\F}{\mathrm{F\,}}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
[$\begin{array}{r@{\,}l} & \lnot(p\iff q)\iff(\lnot p\iff q)\\ 1. & \F\lnot(p\iff q)\iff(\lnot p\iff q)\end{array}$
  [$\begin{array}{r@{\,}l}2. & \T\lnot(p\iff q)\,(1)\\ 3. & \F\lnot p\iff q\,(1)\\ 6. & \F p\iff q\,(2)\end{array}$
    [4
      [8][9]
    ]
    [5
      [10][11]
    ]
  ]
  [$\begin{array}{r@{\,}l}4. & \F\lnot(p\iff q)\,(1)\\ 5. & \T\lnot p\iff q\,(1)\\ 20. & \T p\iff q\,(4)\end{array}$
    [6
      [12][13]
    ]
    [7
      [14][15]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) but I don't think the `\F` and `\T` should be treated as part of the wff. They aren't part of the logical syntax/system of proof. They're semantics rather than syntax. This was not, of course, in any way obvious from the question since the OP provided neither explanation nor markup.

Answer (score 1):

Since `forest` has builtin support for `tabular` nodes, I've modified [Sandy G's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/668471/) to utilise this. I also demonstrate a simple method of circling the contradictions using `tikzmark`. Note that the numbering in the original image is incorrect: there ought not be duplicated line numbers. Hence the solution below has the same number of lines, but appears to have an additional line number (if you don't look carefully).

My column definitions distinguish the individual parts of each line of the proof. By default, all nodes are of type `tab infer` except the first, which is of type `tab theorem`. Assumptions can be created by appending `tab ass`, as show.

- `tab theorem` simply puts its contents into maths mode and expects a `<wff>` as content.
- `tab ass` uses a tripartite definition and expects content in the form `<line number> & <semantic value> & <wff>`.
- `tab infer` uses a four-part definition and expects `<line number> & <semantic value> & <wff> & <reference(s)>`.

All columns are set in text mode by default, except those intended for wffs, which use maths mode. `T` and `F` are not part of the syntax of the language, but rather semantic values. While there's an argument for using maths mode here, they should at least be treated separately in the markup. The line numbers are simple references, so text mode seems most appropriate here, too, though more complex justifications might require some use of maths mode if rules are included.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{array}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
\forestset{%
  declare boolean={only child}{0},
  for tableau/.style={%
    /utils/exec={\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}},
    tab theorem,
    for descendants={tab infer},
    where n children=1{!1.no edge,!1.only child}{},
    before computing xy={%
      where only child={l'=\baselineskip}{}
    }
  },
  tab theorem/.style={math content},
  tab ass/.style={align=rlC},
  tab infer/.style={align=rlCl},
}
\newcommand*{\liff}{\ensuremath{\mathbin{\leftrightarrow}}}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/700793/
% addaswyd o ateb Sandy G.: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/668471/
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tableau,
  [
    \lnot(p\liff q)\liff(\lnot p\liff q)
    [
      1. & F & \lnot(p\liff q)\liff(\lnot p\liff q), tab ass
      [ 2. & T & \lnot(p\liff q) & (1)
        [3. & F & \lnot p\liff q & (1)
          [6. & F & p\liff q & (2)
            [7. & T & \lnot p & (3)
              [8. & F & q & (3)
              [11. & \subnode{fp1}{F} & \subnode{fp2}{p} & (7)
                [13. & \subnode{tp1}{T} & \subnode{tp2}{p} & (6)
                    [14. & F & q & (6)]
                  ]
                  [15. & F & p & (6)
                    [16. & T & q & (6)]
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            ]
            [9. & F & \lnot p & (3)
              [10. & T & q & (3)
                [12. & T & p & (9)
                  [17. & T & p & (6)
                    [18. & F & q & (6)]
                  ]
                  [19. & F & p & (6)
                    [20. & T & q & (6)]
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [4. & F & \lnot(p\liff q) & (1)
        [5. & T & \lnot p\liff q & (1)
          [21. & T & p\liff q & (4)
            [22. & T & \lnot p & (3)
              [23. & T & q & (3)
                [26. & F & p & (7)
                  [27. & T & p & (6)
                    [28. & T & q & (6)]
                  ]
                  [29. & F & p & (6)
                    [30. & F & q & (6)]
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            ]
            [24. & F & \lnot p & (3)
              [25. & F & q & (3)
                [31. & T & p & (9)
                  [32. & T & p & (6)
                    [33. & T & q & (6)]
                  ]
                  [34. & F & p & (6)
                    [35. & F & q & (6)]
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [draw=red,circle,inner sep=0pt,fit=(fp1) (fp2)] {};
    \node [draw=red,circle,inner sep=0pt,fit=(tp1) (tp2)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: tableau proof using forest's tabular support]

Note that this makes a rather wide proof. While you could reduce `s sep`, I think something like `sidewaysfigure` would probably be required.